# The meaning of causative 'have'

Tags: passive-voice, causative-verbs

> (1) *He had a specialist examine his son.*
>
> (2) *He had his son examined by a specialist.*

About this pair, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 1236) says:

> we have equivalence between (1) and (2)

This I think means that we have equivalence *in meaning* between them.

But as for an apparently similar pair, Paul M. Postal says in his paper "[On Raising](http://seas3.elte.hu/coursematerial/denDikkenMarcel/Paul_M._Postal-On_Raising__One_Rule_of_English_Grammar_and_Its_Theoretical_Implications-The_MIT_Press_(1974).pdf)" (page 320):

> Thus, on one reading at least, the following are not semantically equivalent:
>
> (86) a. Tom had Melvin interrogate the witness.
>
> b. Tom had the witness interrogated by Melvin.

I don't see any reason for treating the examples in CGEL and 'On Raising' differently, so why is it that CGEL says the passivation doesn't change the meaning whereas Postal says it does change the meaning "on one reading at least"?

### EDIT

In order to make it clear what Postal means by "on one reading", here's a summary of what Postal says in pages 318-320:

> Right before the cited portion, Postal mentions "a dualistic analysis" found with "*allow*, *permit*, and *order*". By the "dualistic analysis" I think he means that these verbs of permission can have two different meanings, depending on whether to consider them to be 'raising verbs' or not.

So, I think Postal's "on one reading" refers to reading (86) as not having a 'raising' construction, because passivation wouldn't change the meaning in a 'raising' construction.

Apparently, Postal thinks that Postal's (86) can be construed as not involving a 'raising' construction, whereas CGEL thinks that CGEL's (1)/(2) can only be construed as involving a 'raising' construction.

Having said that, I think a more specific question is this:

**Is there any reason for this different treatment?
Or is either Postal or CGEL mistaken?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant that there was one possible sense of (86b) that was not causative, but rather interpretable like _Tom had his tires slashed last night_. That sense is all but impossible with (a), so they would be different. But there is also the more usual causative sense of (b), and on that interpretation they're identical. OK?

Comment: @JohnLawler If you read pages 318-320 of Postal, I think you'd agree that Postal meant something other than what you're "pretty sure that he meant". Please see my edit.

Comment: Unless the alternate reading is "Tom had the witness [that was] interrogated by Melvin", I don't see any difference.

Comment: @AmI I doubt (86b) could ever mean your alternative reading. I think that the alternative reading intended by Postal might be "Tom got the witness to be interrogated by Melvin".

Comment: but that means the same as "Tom got Melvin to interrogate the witness."

Comment: @AmI I think _Tom got Melvin to interrogate the witness_ means that it was Melvin, not the witness, that Tom influenced to conduct the interrogation, whereas _Tom got the witness to be interrogated by Melvin_ I think means that it was the witness, but not Melvin, that Tom influenced to cooperate with the interrogation.

Comment: Don't forget that 'raising' is a trick to turn an event into a direct object -- you aren't allowed to assume that its subject (raised to object) has any special connection to the calling verb.  You can only assume that Tom caused the interrogation to happen, not how he caused it.

Comment: @AmI That's assuming the 'get' constructions involve 'raising'. I'm saying that the 'get' constructions do not involve 'raising'.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the OP.  I hope someone can explain the *dual analysis* because I don't see it. (Are you agreeing with Postal?)

Comment: @AmI I agree with him with respect to verbs of permission (allow, permit, order) being subject to the dualistic analysis, but I'm not sure whether the same dualistic analysis applies to the verb 'have'.

Comment: I do not find the first two sentences in the question equivalent. Especially when it comes to a source on grammar, I find it shocking that the distinction between them is neglected. (1) He had a *specialist* examine his son—as opposed to having somebody else examine him. (2) He had *his son* examined by a specialist—as opposed to having his daughter examined.

Comment: @JasonBassford Do you think that Postal's "dualistic analysis" applies to CGEL's (1)/(2) as well as Postal's (86)? Even if it does, that doesn't mean that CGEL's (1) and (2) should always be different in meaning.

Comment: @JK2 I don't believe there is any difference between the first set of sentences and the second. The fact that different sources give different interpretations is not at all surprising.  But the use of *on one reading at least* is to be applauded, because it makes it clear that there *are* different interpretations. By simply saying *we have equivalence*, without clarification, is a dangerously overgeneralized form of prescription. Both may be saying the same thing (and agreeing with each other)  *in certain interpretations*, but only Postal is giving an open-ended analysis.

Comment: @JK2 I have no opinion at all on the use of the word *raising* here. Aside from the fact that it just sounds like jargon to me.

Comment: @JasonBassford Why don't you read 318-320 of Postal and write up an answer?

Comment: @JK2 I have no interest in providing a full answer. My original comment is sufficient for me: *I do not find the first two sentences in the question equivalent.*

Comment: @JasonBassford - I agree that the choice of subject is always relevant *in context*, but that is true for any verb.

Comment: (86) a. 'Tom had Melvin interrogate the witness.' default-paraphrases to '(86) a'. Tom got Melvin to interrogate the witness.'  // (86) b. 'Tom had the witness interrogated by Melvin.' paraphrases to (86) b'. 'Tom swung it so that the witness was interrogated by Melvin.' //// There is a change in the point of application of coercion.

Answer (score 1):

I’m a bit loath to offer an answer when there are so many erudite comments, but I’m interested in the topic and can’t comment yet, so here goes.

I think the explanation is semantic - besides the non-causative sense illustrated by *Bill had his tires slashed last night*, there seem to be two causative senses of had, roughly (1) to exercise authority over someone such that they use their agency in a particular way (2) to bring about some situation through your own agency. I think Post’s first example invites sense (1), while his second invites sense (2), as do both of Huddleston & Pullum’s – so naturally Post judges his sentences to be different, while Huddleston & Pullum judge theirs to be the same.

The scenario Post’s first sentence conjures up for me is that Tom is some sort of lead investigator and has authority over Melvin, which he exercises by getting Melvin – as opposed to someone else on the team – to conduct the interrogation. That’s sense (1).

Huddleston & Pullum’s first sentence is different in that we have no reason to suppose the father has any authority over the specialist. For one thing, that’s not how the world works – while investigators generally have superiors who get to tell them what to do, there isn’t usually a comparable relationship between specialists and the fathers of their patients. For another thing, we are invited to relate the father to the son rather than the specialist, both for the obvious reason and because the reference is to *a specialist* and not a specific person. All of that points to sense (2).

I think Post’s second sentence is also an example of sense (2). An interrogation is not normally something we undergo voluntarily, so if Tom has power to force the witness into it, it’s a coercive power. At the point where you are coercing someone into something, their agency is no longer in play, which means it can only be sense (2). In any case, I read H&P as saying that *had* never has sense (1) in the passive construction, and as I say below I think they're right.

On that basis, Post’s two examples are using had in two different senses (of course, all that is necessary to explain his statement is that they can plausibly be read as using it in two different senses).

As for Huddleston & Pullum’s second example, it’s quite plausible that the father would have authority over the son, so either sense could be in play, and maybe it comes down to whether you think that the passive construction is compatible with sense (1) – or maybe it’s enough to point out that H&P don’t. At least, that’s how I read p. 1236, where they say *he got his son to be examined by a specialist* is not an alternant of *he got his son examined by a specialist*, and has no equivalent using *have*. As far as I can see, the first of those sentences expresses the same thing as my sense (1), and what H&P are saying is that there is no passive sentence with have that does the same job. If that’s how they see it, they’re bound to read both of their sentences in sense (2), and judge them to be the same.

For what it’s worth, I think H&P are right – you can come up with active sentences with have and got that are equivalent and express sense (1) – e.g. *he had his son tail the specialist* / *he got his son to tail the specialist* - but I’ve drawn a blank as far as passive sentences are concerned. Is it possible that the raising construction requires more arguments than are licensed by this use of have?

Comment: If a son was examined by a specialist, who do you think normally would have paid the specialist? Maybe his father? I don't know about the father having any authority over the specialist, but he can easily be the one who asked the specialist to examine his son. And I think that's enough to convey sense (1).

Comment: Well if you redefine sense (1) in that way, I think it's better to look at it syntactically. I'm not totally clear whether you're saying both sentences mean *he got a specialist to examine his son*, or only the first one. I can't read the second one in that sense, and the idea that the whole event constitutes a single argument seems to explain this very neatly - we then end up with the *to bring about a situation directly* meaning by virtue of the syntax.

Comment: How would you explain the meaning of 'on one reading at least' in Postal's book? I think this wording suggests that Postal's (86a) and (86b) are "semantically equivalent" on another reading. And in all likelihood on this "another reading" CGEL seems to be basing its analysis that (1) and (2) are semantically equivalent.

Comment: More importantly, if you take time to read through pages 318-320 of Postal, you will realize that your answer is not in line with what Postal is trying to say regarding the "one reading" of (86).

Comment: @JK2 Well, the two basic readings of *Tom had Melvin interrogate the witness* are a) [Tom caused Melvin (Melvin interrogates witness)] and b) [Tom caused (Melvin interrogates witness)]  - that’s clear from 318. Without delving further into the book it’s not clear to me whether Postal thinks *Tom had the witness interrogated by Melvin* can be read in sense a), but clearly it can be read in sense b).

Comment: It follows that you can read both sentences in sense b), corresponding to what I called ‘bringing about the situation directly’. If you do read them that way, it doesn’t matter which way round you describe the situation. [Tom caused (Melvin interrogates witness)] means the same thing as [Tom caused (witness interrogated by Melvin)]. Hence on one reading they are equivalent.

Comment: On the other hand, you can read the first sentence in sense a) and the second in sense b), in which case they are obviously not equivalent – the second would then mean [Tom caused (witness interrogated by Melvin)], which is equivalent to [Tom caused (Melvin interrogates witness)], so clearly not the same as [Tom caused Melvin (Melvin interrogates witness)].

Comment: I find it pretty implausible that H&P, in saying that their two sentences are equivalent, mean only that they are equivalent on one of two possible readings - especially given that H seems to have been the first to point out that this type of sentence can often be read in two ways. It’s possible I suppose, but it strikes me as more likely that they just don’t think *have* behaves like *allow*.

Comment: I would disagree with them there – I think it’s possible to read their first sentence as [he caused a specialist (specialist examines son)], in which case it’s not equivalent to their second sentence. As I said in my answer, I think they set it up in a way that invites the reading [he caused (specialist examines son)], and on that reading it would be equivalent – but I don’t think the other reading is impossible.

Comment: Seeing as (1) and (2) label sentences rather than meanings, please clarify what meanings "sense (1)" and "sense (2)" are intended to indicate. // Another issue that needs sorting out is what "a" means. To me, sentence (1) indicates that the father chose the specialist, whereas it isn't clear from sentence (2) whether he chose the specialist or rather chose a medical org which chose which of their specialists would examine the son.

Comment: On one reading: (a) = *Melvin was ordered by Tom to interrogate the witness* – this is direct. Tom spoke to Melvin. (b) = *Tom arranged [via his secretary or some other indirect way] for the witness to be interrogated by Melvin.*  – this form lacks the explicit Tom to Melvin interaction. -- The credible distinction might be made, for example, if Melvin interrogated the witness to death and Tom was being accused of negligence, Tom’s defence is that he explicitly said to his secretary “and no rough stuff” but the secretary forgot to pass on that part of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **had** in neither of the sentences below  means "ate for dinner" or "tricked" or "was stuck with as a partner" but "arranged to happen, caused", and assuming that the noun references are not intoned in a way to indicate some confusion on the part of the listener, as in "no, not Marvin,  Melvin!"

a. Tom had Melvin interrogate the witness.

b. Tom had the witness interrogated by Melvin.

Tom arranged to have Melvin interrogate the witness.

Tom arranged to have the witness be interrogated by Melvin.

The practical meaning is the same.  If you don't think it is the same, please  offer your paraphrases.

Comment: (86) a. 'Tom had Melvin interrogate the witness.' default-paraphrases to '(86) a'. Tom got Melvin to interrogate the witness.' // (86) b. 'Tom had the witness interrogated by Melvin.' paraphrases to (86) b'. 'Tom swung it so that the witness was interrogated by Melvin.' //// There is a change in the point of application of coercion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  The nuances you detect between "got" and "swung it so that" are not entailed in these sentences. You're "reading things into" these statements.  In both cases "arranged to have" is a neutral reading.

Comment: Tom had the shop repair the car. Tom had the car repaired by the shop.

Comment: Whether the paraphrase is *plausible in the real world* is not a grammatical issue, is it? Tom had his son visit the Vatican. Tom had the Vatican visited by his son.   That Tom has no power over the Vatican is not relevant if Tom is not ordering anyone but simply "setting things in motion".  The Vatican got visited in either case.

Comment: 'The practical meaning is the same' is what I'm disagreeing with. Pragmatics is often even more important than grammar. 'Have someone do something' quite strongly implies (though does not mandate) strong persuasion/coercion on the 'someone'. 'Have something done by someone' just shows organisational prowess.

Comment: That's where we partly disagree.  It *can* imply "throwing one's weight around" when the subject and the object have some sort of well-known relationship (*Don Corleone had the Chief of Police tear up his parking tickets*) but it doesn't entail such a relationship. *He had a specialist examine his son* means merely that he arranged to have a specialist examine his son, most probably after a three-month wait. He took the necessary steps to see that his son was examined by a specialist. It's really no different from *He had a mechanic listen to the noise coming from his car.*

Comment: It can imply vs 'means merely' is a significant difference.